# Javascript addition results unwanted zeros

Tags: javascript

This looks like simple but really weird why this happens. Consider below example

```
var a = ['1.53','3.00','5.00'];
var total = 0;
a.forEach(function(t){
total += Number(t)
});
console.log(total)//9.530000000000001
```

This prints 9.530000000000001 instead of 9.53. This could be fixed by total.toFixed(2). But please advise why the 0000000000001 added in the result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: because in js all numbers are floating point

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/ refer this URL